# Installing additional threaded version of Tcl/Tk and run code on certain nodes in a cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, centos, tcl, cluster-computing, pre-compilation

I need to paralleling a code written in tcl/tk language,in a cluster have 12 nodes my IP is registered to access to 4 nodes, every node have 4 processors with 2 cores each. the OS is linux centos 64 bit, I have the admin user pass and a normal user pass.

so my question the installation of the tcl/tk. could be done on each node! in a way not changing the version works on other nodes!?. if it can be done, then how to link or launch one of the versions. to compile the code!

or it should be done for all the cluster!, and the previous running should be stopped for all other user meanwhile updating the code in all nodes for all users.
The code works with tcl/tk 8.4.

i have not thread version 8.4.7. I installed a new version in one directory in one of the nodes 4.8.14 threaded. but using the tclshell just gives me the old version platform. so should this be done changing the $PATH.

when I Issue echo $PATH  in a node I cannot see any specific directory of tcl. maybe its in the root. but I donot know if it is the global root or just the node root!

Comment: Please give us some other details. How did you installed the (I think) 8.4.14 version? Are you really using a cluster computer? If so, you should not care about spreading threads or processes among nodes, because it's a load balancer job. If you add some clarification, you'll get answer more easely!

Comment: Getting a particular application to work well in a clustered environment requires cooperation from the application, whatever language it is written in. The first place to look at therefore must be the application's documentation. Failing that, the application's support system. For _us_ to help, we'd need a lot more information.